# Dynamically loading BPL fails in LoadLibrary

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, bpl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I would like to load BPL modules dynamically in Delphi 10 Seattle (Update 1) or Delphi 10.1 Berlin project (Enterprise version). But [LoadPackage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.LoadPackage) function fails with message (on both 32 and 64 bit target platforms):

---

**Project LoadPackageTest.exe raised exception class EPackageError with message 'Can't load package "real path here"\TestBplPackage.bpl.
The specified module could not be found'.**

---

My development platform is Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

I am sure that the filename passed is correct (it contains the full path). 
What I have done up to now:

- The same project group works without problems (I had to re-create it from scratch) if compiled with Delphi 2007 Enterprise - on the same Win 10 PC
- If I load standard .DLL - it is loaded properly and I can call functions in D2007, D10 and D10.1 (works for both 32 and 64 bit targets on D10 and D10.1).

Actually LoadPackage calls SafeLoadLibrary, which calls LoadLibrary (all these procedures are in System.SysUtils.

I compiled the testing executable with and without Run Time packages
There is the code:

### DLL project (TestDLL.dpr), works in all cases

```
library TestDLL;
uses SysUtils, Classes;
{$R *.res}
function GetMyTime: TDateTime; stdcall; 
begin 
  Result:= Now; 
end;
exports GetMyTime;
end.
```

### BPL Project (TestBplPackage.dpr)

```
package TestBplPackage;
{ standard compiler directives - the project was created with New->Package}
requires
  rtl,
  vcl; 
contains
  TestBPLUnit in 'TestBPLUnit.pas';
end.
```

---

```
unit TestBPLUnit;
interface
function GetMyTime: TDateTime; stdcall;

implementation 
uses  classes, sysutils;  

function GetMyTime: TDateTime;
begin  
  Result:= Now;
end;
exports  GetMyTime;
end.
```

### Testing application - LoadPackageTest.dpr

Form1: TForm contains dOpen: TOpenDialog and a Button1: TButton

```
type
  TMyDateTimeFunction = function: TDateTime; stdcall;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ext: string;
  h: HModule;
  func: TMyDateTimeFunction;
begin
  if dOpen.Execute then begin
    ext:= ExtractFileExt(dOpen.FileName);
    if SameText(ext, '.bpl') then begin
      h:= LoadPackage(PChar(dOpen.FileName));
      if h > 0 then begin
        func:= GetProcAddress(h, 'GetMyTime');
        if Assigned(func) then
          ShowMessage(FormatDatetime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', func));
        UnloadPackage(h);
      end;
    end else if SameText(ext, '.dll') then begin
      h:= LoadLibrary(PChar(dOpen.FileName));
      if h > 0 then begin
        func:= GetProcAddress(h, 'GetMyTime');
        if Assigned(func) then
          ShowMessage(FormatDatetime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', func));
        FreeLibrary(h);
      end;
    end;
  end; //dOpen.execute
end;
```

Has anybody tried something similar?

Avoid deleting unit from "Contains" node of the Project manager tree - both Delphi 10 and 10.1 crash...

---

### EDIT 1: It works on some conditions

Thanks to the David's answer, I managed to achieve some progress:
it works properly when the contents of the relevant
    *C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Redist\*
*Win32* or *Win64* subfolders is either in the folder where the application and the test BPL are or in relevant *System32* or *SysWOW64* folder.

Without the above, I could not manage to make it working despite the fact that both
    *C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin* and
    *C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin64*
were in the %PATH% Environment variable. It was not finding the **RTL** package.

---

There is an easy to be explained side effect if an application relies on the %PATH% variable to find the necessary BPLs. Because I have  C:\Windows\SysWOW64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS
in the %PATH% variable, if I compile for Win32 platform with run time packages, I get the following error message:
**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)**
which is because a 32 bit application attempts to load 64 bit BPLs.

I can easily swap the places of System32 and SysWOW64, but this is the global, not the user path variable and requires restart for the changes to take effect.
I will continue to experiment, but up to now the only 100% working solution is to keep the used "***standard***" BPLs into the platform output folder.

Comment: I can't replicate this - made a new BPL project, copy, paste, build; made a new VCL application, added the button and opendialog, copy, paste, build.  Ran the application, selected the BPL, saw the current time in a message box.  D10-Seattle on Win7.

Comment: @J... Is your Win 7 64 bit? Did you try both 32 and 64 bit target platforms?

Comment: Yes, 64-bit OS.  I built only for 32-bit - you said it didn't work with either platform so I presume whatever the problem is, it isn't related to the platform.

Comment: @J... Thanks for the quick note. It appears to be more complicated - see my notes I added to the question.

Comment: Put the path back to default. Read about file system redirection. Then put the necessary dependent packges in the eve dir. Or just stop using packages.

Comment: SysWOW64 should not be in your path.

Comment: Thank you all! I felt into MS folder naming trap again. I removed SysWOW64 from PATH (do not remember adding it myself?), placed the contents redist\winNN into the RIGHT folders (Win32 into SysWOW64 and Win64 into System32) and everything works like charm!

Comment: Don't put files into the system directories. They are for the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception text indicates that the call to `LoadLibrary` failed and `GetLastError` returned `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. There are two common explanations for this:

1. The package file cannot be found by the DLL search. Perhaps the name was wrong, or the package is not in a location searched by the DLL search algorithm.
2. The package file can be found, but one of its dependencies cannot be found. For instance, perhaps the `rtl` package cannot be found.

Debug the issue using Dependency Walker. Use it in profile mode and it will tell you which module cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you, David! But I get the following from Dependency Walker:
LoadLibraryW("C:\rumen\work\dX\Packages\TestBplPackage.bpl") called from "LOADPACKAGETEST.EXE" at address 0x000000000043ED00.

Loaded "TESTBPLPACKAGE.BPL" at address 0x0000000004FB0000.  Successfully hooked module.

LoadLibraryW("C:\rumen\work\dX\Packages\TestBplPackage.bpl") returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).


All things (.exe, .bpl, .dll) are in the same folder. 
On D2007 it was tested under the same conditions. And I took the D2007 project group into D10...

Comment: The error message cannot really be argued with. The only sane explanations are to be found in my answer. Clearly the module or one of its dependencies cannot be found. Now you have to work out why.

Comment: A special case of (1) is when somehow the working directory is not what is expected? Or does Delphi forcedly check the same directory as the exe too for dynamic loading?